# How to exit the video full screen by pressing the back button

Tags: java, android, webview, fullscreen, exit

I have an app to read the news, it is a simple WebView.
It can happen that on the web page there is a video, and if I open the video to a full screen there are two ways to exit the full-screen mode (It is not a YouTube video):

1. press the special button [exit full-screen mode] button - it works fine
2. press the back button - having many issues with it

The video is closed and WebView goes back to the previous page if I use this code. I do not like it because the web page scrolls up and down after I go back... server-side issues.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to detect the full-screen mode, and based on the retrieved info exit the full-screen mode or go back to the previous page?

Thank you,
Alex.